# p:scrollpanel not working inside a p:notification bar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to apply scroll panel inside a notification bar of prime faces, content is visible but scroll is not working.

Can anyone help me?

The code is given below have a look. Thanks.

```
<p:notificationBar position="top" effect="slide" style="margin-left:30px;width:500px;margin-top:51px;height:300px" styleClass="top" widgetVar="bar">
                <p:scrollPanel style="width:400px;height:280px">
                <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean blandit tortor a ipsum vehicula, in semper sapien auctor. Nulla tempor eget est non consequat. Nulla sit amet lorem justo. Cras non tellus eros. Sed ultricies orci ut quam interdum fringilla. Nam vitae massa ac mi elementum mattis vel vitae sem. Ut eros ipsum, scelerisque a erat a, eleifend luctus nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
        Vivamus ac ullamcorper magna. Aenean felis ante, elementum sit amet urna at, eleifend aliquet velit. Morbi a convallis magna. In nec leo vel dolor hendrerit pharetra. Cras in iaculis enim. Aenean porta sapien dignissim turpis dapibus, eu dictum velit elementum. Aliquam sollicitudin gravida luctus.
    </p>
    <p>
        Ut vel nulla sit amet erat laoreet eleifend nec sed lacus. Quisque placerat diam vitae justo eleifend, rutrum mollis mauris fringilla. Curabitur turpis odio, euismod id lorem a, ultricies suscipit ligula. Pellentesque ut erat a leo rhoncus porta ac sed velit. Nunc at erat ligula. Fusce vehicula posuere interdum. Curabitur tempus, tortor at sollicitudin dapibus, erat ante varius nisl, id dictum erat ipsum porttitor ipsum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla id varius enim, sed rutrum orci.
    </p>

</p:scrollPanel>
</p:notificationBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `mode` attribute value to `native` of the `<p:scrollPanel>`:

```
<p:scrollPanel mode="native"...>
```

Unfortunately I don't know what it is mean and what the other enabled values. But when I set it to this value the scrollPanel got working in this component.